# Wipe a directory tree

Tags: c, file-system, posix

The idea here is to destroy the data in a directory tree by finding any files in it and overwriting their data with garbage before deleting them. The function returns minus the number of errors encountered, or zero if successful.

`Obliterate.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
static char B[FILENAME_MAX];
static int RM(const size_t len) {
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(B, &st))
        return -1;
    if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
        DIR *const dir = opendir(B);
        if (!dir)
            return -1;
        B[len] = '/';
        for (struct dirent *dirent; (dirent = readdir(dir));) {
            if (memcmp(dirent->d_name, ".", 2) && memcmp(dirent->d_name, "..", 3)) {
                const size_t namelen = strlen(dirent->d_name);
                char *const ptr = (char *)memcpy(B+len+1, dirent->d_name, namelen)+namelen;
                *ptr = 0;
                const int tmp = RM(ptr-B);
                if (tmp)
                    return closedir(dir)+tmp-1;
            }
        }
        B[len] = 0;
        if (closedir(dir))
            return -1;
    } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
        const int fd = open(B, O_WRONLY);
        if (fd == -1)
            return -1;
        for (char buf[BUFSIZ]; st.st_size > 0; st.st_size -= BUFSIZ) {
            const size_t size = st.st_size > BUFSIZ ? BUFSIZ : st.st_size;
            arc4random_buf(buf, size);
            if (write(fd, buf, size) < size)
                return close(fd)-1;
        }
        if (close(fd))
            return -1;
    }
    return remove(B);
}
int main(const int argc, const char *const *argv) {
    while (*++argv) {
        const size_t len = strlen(*argv);
        memcpy(B, *argv, len);
        if (RM(len))
            perror(*argv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that overwriting like `shred` is only effective for filesystems that write file data in-place, without journalling, on disks with no translation layer (i.e. not most SSDs today)?

Comment: I suggest that you read https://www.blancco.com/resources/blog-comprehensive-list-data-wiping-erasure-standards/ ; this is a solved problem and unfortunately yours is very unlikely to be an acceptable solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is very dense, to the extent that it harms readability.  I'm not a fan of variable names such as `B`, especially for globals.  We could do with better layout and more comments.  And I recommend always using compound statements with loops and conditionals, even when the body is a single statement and `{…}` aren't strictly required.

Compilation warns that there's no visible definition of `arc4random_buf()`.  I strongly urge you to require prototypes for all functions that are used rather than fallback back to "implicit `int`".

I would use `strcmp()` rather than `memcmp()` with hand-crafted lengths when testing for `.` and `..`, to more clearly convey intent and to eliminate even the possibility of mismatch.  Similarly, prefer `strcpy()` (or `strncpy`) to `memcpy` when copying arguments or directory entries into `B`.

`memcpy()` returns a `void*`, so there's no need to cast to assign it to a `char*` variable.

We have no defence against overflowing the end of `B`.  `FILENAME_MAX` is *not* a guarantee that we can't create longer path names!  Consider changing directory to keep pathnames relative and avoid the need for copying altogether.

Error messages aren't particularly informative: `perror(*argv)` shows only the argument at the root of the failure, but users are more likely to be interested in the actual file where the problem occurred.

Opening a file with `O_WRONLY` may well cause the file to be truncated on the first write, and new storage allocated - there's no expectation that the new contents will overwrite the disk blocks previously allocated to the file.  In any case, overwriting like `shred` is only effective for filesystems that write file data in-place, without journalling, on disks with no translation layer (i.e. not most SSDs today).  Even on files where that expectation is valid, I would lean towards `mmap()` for in-place overwriting.

Comment: On my implementation (MacOS), `arc4random_buf()` seems to be included in `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: That's evidently a platform-specific extension, and not part of standard C or POSIX.  Not sure if there's a portable way to get that function.